# Java j label listener

Tags: java

I am trying to access start menu when I clicked on a JLabel,but I can't find the location.how can I do it?

```
l6.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        l6MouseClicked(e);
    }
    private void l6MouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start shell:startmenufolder");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Dsk1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: "cmd /c start shell:startmenufolder" this location is not working

Comment: because "this location" is an invalid command. Thats how you open the windows start menu, apparently : https://community.oracle.com/thread/1393115?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks ,this is working :)